# why is lighttpd adding an extra Connection: close

Tags: lighttpd

```
POST /test/test_service HTTP/1.0
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8;action="http://www.test.org/GetImages"
Content-Length: 211
Host: 192.168.1.169
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)
X-Forwarded-For: ::ffff:192.168.1.45
X-Host: 192.168.1.169
X-Forwarded-Proto: http
Connection: close

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://test.org/soap-envelope" xmlns:wsdl="http://www.test.com">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <wsdl:GetImages/>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I am sending a HTTP POST method to a web server running lighttpd.
Lighttpd is supposed to forward the request to another software subsystem.
But it seems to be modifying the original request that it received.
Lighttpd web server 1.4.40 is adding this extra field
Connection: close
when its forwarding the POST method to the software subsystem. Any idea why lighttpd is doing that ? Is it not supposed to just forward whatever it receives ?

Any idea how to avoid it ? I couldn't find anything in the configuration to avoid it. Tried a few things such as forcing a "keep-alive". The problem is that the original request from SOAP UI doesn't contain it. But lighttpd is introducing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, lighttpd is intentionally adding `Connection: close` to the request to tell the backend that lighttpd will not be sending additional requests on the same connection to the backend.

Your question fails to indicate why you think this is a problem.  (Hint, it is not a problem and is conformant with the HTTP RFC specifications.)

Aside: lighttpd 1.4.40 was released in July 2016.  That is absurdly out-of-date.  The current lighttpd release is lighttpd 1.4.64.

Comment: Thanks @gstrauss . But the first request should be challenged with a 401 and the client should be sending another request with valid credentials. This transaction will end up with a 200 Ok eventually. By saying there won't be additional requests on the same connection, will this not mess up ?

Comment: & yes unfortunately, we can't go beyond 1.4.40 for various reasons.

Comment: Also @gstrauss, I don't see 1.4.35 exhibiting this behaviour. & the transactions proceeded till 200 OK without a problem. The only difference between lighttpd 1.4.35 and 1.4.40 seems to be just this "Connection: close" parameter.

Comment: "will this not mess up?" => no, it works just fine.  Again, I ask "Why do you think this is a problem?"  Signed, the lighttpd developer who wrote that code in lighttpd and is well-versed in [RFC 7235](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7235) Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP/1.1): Authentication

Comment: @badri "& yes unfortunately, we can't go beyond 1.4.40 for various reasons."  If there is a technical limitation, please post a more detailed question on the [lighttpd forums](https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/boards)